# Replace NAs with blank space instead of " " in a downloaded file of a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app from which I download a txt file. The issue is that I want to replace NAs in my dataframe with total blank space instead of "". I use `data[is.na(data)] <- ""`

```
d1<-c("a","","b")
d2<-c("a","a","b")
d3<-c("","","b")
d4<-c("a","c","b")
d5<-c("","b","b")
NN2<-data.frame(Name,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)
```

## app

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Our dataset
  data <- NN2
  data[is.na(data)] <- ""
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".txt", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.table(data, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The downloaded file should not have " " but blank space.

Comment: I don't understand what the difference between "" and a total blank space. You say you have NA values in your title but your example data doesn't have any NA values, it has zero-length strings. Does this really have anything to do with `shiny`? Or is it really just about using `write.table` to make a text file?

Comment: You can use `quote = FALSE` in `write.table`, but then e.g. `"a"` will no longet have quotes around it either

Comment: I do not think it has to do with shiny but Im not sure about it because I use downloadhandle(). I think the quote=FALSE does the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help :

```
write.table(data, file, na = "", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```